# itunes connect invalid build uploaded from xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, xcode8, macos-sierra

I have uploaded a built on **iTunes connect**. IPA is made from `Xcode 8` macOS Sierra.However the **IPA** is uploaded successfully without any issue, but on iTunes connect build is not visible in Activity. But when I add on + icon to add new build for submission in that list build is coming with red ! in its side showing this build is invalid. Please help.

Comment: i just checked mail and i got this The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: you need to add this two privacy terms in info.plist with proper message

Comment: @Maul what message ?

Comment: Give proper description for what you are using this NSCalendarsUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

For Example you are using photos app for set profile picture, You need to give message like "To set Profile Picture in application"

Comment: @MuhammadNoman no need to check provisioning Profile. Its all about privacy terms which is new feature added by apple. You must have define this terms in info.plist if you are using this feature in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Add this to your info.plist

set messages depending upon your needs

Comment: @niket if you solve your problem using this answer then mark this as accepted so other can use this Thanks

Comment: can i update plist for an app reviewed on iTunes connect or do i have to upload new IPA ?

Comment: @niket Upload a new ipa

Comment: Can You please write Your proper answer in Description . I can't See properly in image.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia if you want to use calendar service in your application then you have to add below privacy terms into your .plist file
Privacy - Calendars Usage Description - "Appropriate message"

Answer (score 0):

I've written description for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and `NSCameraUsageDescription` keys, once I upload **IPA** universal build is processing first, it's not visible after 2minutes on Activity tab. If I tab on Build with plus symbol,it showing up previous build, recent build showing as

> This build is invalid with red flag.

but it's working fine for iPhone alone. but Universal build is not uploading.

Answer (score 0):

just check your mail they provide with reason.In my case I have `invalid cfbundleexecutable` in its `info.plist`

Because I just Drag and Drop The `SDK` In folder include `info.plist` file which is not in use. That's create the issue for me. So find the unused `info.plist` file and delete it from the Source code. `Clean` the project folder and `Re upload`.
Hope This Helpful